# Как работает аутентификация с использованием Qr кода?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, token, qrcode

Недавно Microsoft выпустили свою программу для [авторизации по Qr кодам](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/account/authenticator). Видимо, технология становится все популярнее и популярнее...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, куда копать, чтобы добавить возможность её применения на свой сервис на NodeJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта технология называется *One Time Password*. Различают два стандарта реализации: [HOTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOTP) и [TOTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm). Однако, **Google отклоняется от обоих стандартов**, поэтому рационально применить абстракцию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Благо, есть готовый модуль [optlib](https://github.com/yeojz/otplib). Он написан на TypeScript (в процессе интеграции будет доступен *IntelliSense*), имеет наибольшее количество скачиваний среди альтернатив. Есть готовая [UMD сборка для браузеров](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@otplib/preset-browser). Модуль можно применить как для генерации кодов для сторонних сервисов, так и для реализации авторизации на своем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я отсканировал подобный обычным сканнером Qr кодов. Из содержания становится понятно, что и Google и Microsoft негласно поддерживают протокол со следующей компоновкой:

```
otpauth://totp/example-user?secret=SON2SDBXH2KXYK5A
```

И действительно, при попытке открыть как ссылку, в [Microsoft Authenticator](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/account/authenticator) появилась новая позиция...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]